# Run specific RPC commands in PHP?

Tags: json-rpc, php

I'm trying to get the balance of a specific address in my PHP session, I currently have this:

```
<?php
  require 'header.php';
  include 'Includes/Bitcoin/easybitcoin.php';
  $bitcoin = new Bitcoin('user', 'password', 'localhost', '8332');
  $wallet = $_SESSION['UserWallet'];
  $balance = $bitcoin->getbalance($wallet);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
</head>
<body style="font-family: sans-serif;">
  <b>Wallet address: <?php print_r($wallet); ?></b>
  <br />
  <b>Account balance: ฿<?php print_r($balance); ?></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the `$_SESSION['UserWallet']` contains the bitcoin address, when I run this it returns an error, how does it work?

Comment: That is not how the getbalance RPC works.

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation before trying to make a product that handles other people's money.

Comment: @PieterWuille What parameters are used? Can they be variables in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the balance of something you need an account, which is best created dynamically with PHP. You would use the `getnewaddress("echo uniqid()");` in PHP as an example of generating a new account for every user.